# CSS perspective on a long, scrollable div

Tags: css, html, transform, css-transforms

I've got a click style that involves **tilting the element via a 3D rotate when clicked on**. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Click effect]

And [here is a GIF of the effect working properly with a short list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FeE9.gif)!

I have perspective on the parent div set at about 1500px, and the list div is set to inherit perspective. When this scrollable div gets really long, though, you start to see effects like this when clicking elements toward the bottom of the list:

[image: Click effect with a larger div]

I'm assuming this is because the perspective is applied to the entire height of the div, rather than just the visible height. I tried to resolve this by having the perspective of the list div inherit from the parent div (who's height is only the visible area), but this had no effect.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

EDIT: Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="artists">
        <li>38 Special</li>
        <li>A Flock Of Seagulls</li>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1500px;
}

ul.artists {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* Animation stuff, list styles, etc */
    perspective: inherit;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When pressed, a style like this is applied to the list item:

```
{
    transform: rotate3d(4.05, 6.1635, 0, 15deg);
}
```

**EDIT: Repro here:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqAhK

Notice how as you scroll down the list, the perspective is applied as though the viewport is as high as the list itself, rather than the container - resulting in a different effect depending on your position in the list! How can I get perspective to be applied on the list items using the dimensions of the container only?

My best workaround would be to freeze the list and set a static height on the click event, but that has some side effects and is a somewhat hacky solution!

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML structure and CSS please? CSS can be one tricky beast.

Comment: Added! Apologies for omitting that.

Comment: Alrighty, attempting to test and reproduce...  EDIT: I'm getting the opposite rotation then what you had in the picture. Is there any CSS missing?

Comment: That's intentional, the item rotates depending on where it was pressed. The problem is that this rotation effect doesn't persist so far down the scrollable div due to the perspective.

Comment: That's the code that needs to be checked out then, because there's no problem with the CSS as far as I can tell.

Comment: I added a repro case to the bottom of the post; see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqAhK

Notice how as you scroll the list, the effect of the transform changes due to the perspective being applied across the entire height of the contained list element. How can I get the perspective to apply just based on the viewport of the container div?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but...

```
ul.list li {
  perspective: inherit;
}
```

...changing it so that the `<li>` elements themselves are what reset the perspective, rather than the container `<ul>`, seems to make all the elements appear the same.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGpKk

Comment: Didn't think to apply that to the elements themselves! One moment, testing against actual implementation :)

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to remove perspective entirely! See this Codepen that generates the same effect; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmeG

Comment: Are you in Chrome? Your initial example didn't work in Chrome for me either, but was just fine in IE/Firefox.

Comment: Nope, in IE - it doesn't work in Chrome just due to missing vendor prefixes :)

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.